# JLabel's text is not changing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

EDIT: Huge code re-organisation, old question here: http://pastebin.com/Mbg4dYiY

I have created a basic program that is designed to show the weather in a window using Swing. I am developing using IntelliJ and I have used the UI builder in that. I am attempting to fetch some information from the Weather Underground servers and then make a JLabel called `weatherlabel` display this information. However, the JLabel doesn't actually change in the window; it just stays as 'Weather Will Go Here'. How do I fix this?

Here is my main.java:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Display d = new Display();
        d.getandsetWeather();
    }

}
```

Here is my Display.java:

```
public class Display {

    Display disp = this;

    public JPanel myPanel;
    public JLabel weatherfield;
    private JButton button1;

    public void init() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display");
        frame.setContentPane(new Display().myPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(480, 234));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void getandsetWeather() {
        String editedline = null;
        init();
        try {
            // Construct data
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

            // Send data
            URL url = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/772a9f2cf6a12db3/geolookup/conditions/q/UK/Chester.json");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                if( line.contains("\"weather\":")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    editedline = line.replace("\"weather\":\"", "");
                    editedline = editedline.replace("\",", "");
                    System.out.println(editedline);
                    weatherfield.setText(editedline);
                }


            }
            wr.close();
            rd.close();
            weatherfield.setText(editedline);
            System.out.println(weatherfield.getText());
            weatherfield.repaint();
            weatherfield.revalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!" + e);
        }


    }

}
```

When I run the program, this is printed to the log:

```
Hello World!
        "weather":"Scattered Clouds",
        Scattered Clouds
        Scattered Clouds
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: you might need to revalidate or repaint the layout. like this: d.weatherfield.revalidate(); or d.weatherfield.repaint(); repaint() should be enough.

Comment: @LeoPflug, repainting didn't make any difference; thanks though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, will do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You seem to have a strange understanding of OOP and code-flow
2. You have to `main` methods, one of which you are trying to call the other `main` method. Don't do that. A program should only have one `main` method. You should *never* have to this

   ```
   Display.main(new String[]{});
   ```
3. Why even have this `ChangeWeatherLabelText` class? There is only one method, that doesn't seem to be needed in it's own class. Your instantiation if `Display` in that method does nothing to the rest of the program. So you call has no effect on the label.
4. Instead of 3, put that method in the class that actually has the label and just reference the label field in the method.
5. Also, `GetWeather` just seems like a helper class with a helper method. "Helper" class methods are useless if they don't return something.
6. IMHO, you should restructure your entire program. Some things may work now, but there's a lot of bad practice going on in your code
7. If I were to write this program, all the code would be in one file. If you insist on them being in separate files, you need to learn how to use constructors and how to pass objects to them. That is how you are going to manipulate objects from other classes. That is unless you understand the MVC model, which may be a little advance at this point for you.

---

**UPDATE** with OP update of code

Test this out and be sure to read the comments so you can see what I did. Let me know if you have any question.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        new Display();                        // <-- just instantiate
    }

}

 class Display {

    Display disp = this;

    public JPanel myPanel;               // <--------- Haven't been initialized 
    public JLabel weatherfield;
    private JButton button1;

    public Display() {                   // you need constructor to call init
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        myPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());    // initialize
        weatherfield = new JLabel(" ");              // initialize
        button1 = new JButton("Button");              // initialize
        myPanel.add(weatherfield, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myPanel.add(button1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getandsetWeather();                       // <-------- add listener to call getandsetweather
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display");
        frame.setContentPane(myPanel);   //   <--------------------- fix 1
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(480, 234));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void getandsetWeather() {
        String editedline = null;
        init();
        try {
            // Construct data
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

            // Send data
            URL url = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/772a9f2cf6a12db3/geolookup/conditions/q/UK/Chester.json");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                if( line.contains("\"weather\":")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    editedline = line.replace("\"weather\":\"", "");
                    editedline = editedline.replace("\",", "");
                    System.out.println(editedline);
                    weatherfield.setText(editedline);
                }


            }
            wr.close();
            rd.close();
            weatherfield.setText(editedline);
            System.out.println(weatherfield.getText());
            weatherfield.repaint();
            weatherfield.revalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!" + e);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thought my code was bad! I'm going to do a bit of restructuring now.

Comment: The whole 4 classes thing started because I had a pretty bad idea of how static voids worked, if you're wondering

Comment: It makes sense if you're trying to learn. If you know how to use constructor and how to pass objects to them, this could be accomplished using the four classes. If not, then your best bet is to put everything into one class an have class variables that can be accessed by all methods. That way you know what it is you are going to be accessing. Because the way you're currently doing it, you may thing you're accessing one label, but really you're accessing a totally different one, becuase you're instantiating classes in more than one location.

Comment: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) is a great reference to keep bookmarked

Comment: Bookmarked that Really Big Index, looks interesting. I've restructured my code and updated my question!

Comment: See my **UPDATE** I fixed a few things and added comments that you should look at. Run the program. It works for me.

Comment: Fantastic! This works! Changing it a bit now so it doesn't need a button press. I would have up-voted earlier if I didn't only have 1 rep....

Comment: You can get rid of the `init()` in the `getandsetWeather()`. I judt noticed it now. I think that's why the program flickers when you click the button

Comment: Yeah, I made sure you had more than 1 ;-)

Comment: Cheers @peeskillet, it doesn't flicker anymore. I also made `getandsetWeather()` run on the program's start by changing `new Display();` to `new Display().getandsetWeather();`.